# Strange vertical shift on some pages

Tags: header-footer, geometry

Unfortunately I was not yet able to create a complete MWE since the real content of my document is copyrighted and using blindtext did not create the strange errors.

My problem: I have a large document containing lots of tables etc.

On some pages, the header and footer are slightly vertically offset. When scrolling through the document, some pages "jump" a tiny bit (max a few mm).

Showing the frame of the geometry package reveals, that the borders do not change, the content of the header/footer does however.

Is there - without the MWE - any approach I can take to determine, why some pages are offset?

I think it might be connected to somehow "too much content" on those pages, since the header is offset in the upper direction while the footer is offset downwards...

---

Edit 1: I added the complete preamble for more information. Additional notes: The shifting is not connected to the beginning of sections or subsections.

```
\documentclass[english,footsepline,listof=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{float}

\makeatletter

%% Open a read-channel for later use
\newread\tempfile
\newread\file
\newcommand{\getnextline}

%% Packages for pagelayout and borders/margins of the whole document
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,verbose=true,tmargin=4.5cm,bmargin=3.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm,headheight=3cm,footskip=1.5cm,showframe}
\savegeometry{a4standard}
%\setlength{\footheight}{1cm}

%% Package for nice vertical spacings between the lines
\usepackage{setspace}

%% Begin of magic to indent all body but no headings
\newcommand\LeftMargin{.5cm}
\renewcommand*\sectionlinesformat[4]{ \ifstr{#3}{}{}{\hspace*{-\LeftMargin}}#3#4}
\usepackage[  headwidth=\the\textwidth+\LeftMargin:-\LeftMargin:    \LeftMargin,footwidth=\the\textwidth+\LeftMargin:-\LeftMargin:\LeftMargin]{scrlayer-scrpage}
%% End of magic

%% Define how deep the numeration in the document should be.
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
%% Define how deep the numeration in the table of contents should be.
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
%% Print paragraphs and subparagraphs not in bold
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\normalfont \underline}
\setkomafont{subparagraph}{\normalfont \underline}

\usepackage{tabularx} %package for table on 1st page
\usepackage{longtable} %package for table that is longer than one page
\usepackage{tabu}

%% Using .eps-images
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}

%% Define new columntype for centered output in tabularx/tabu environments
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable} %package for automated csv-table-creation
\usepackage{pgfplots} %see above
\usepackage{colortbl} %allows coloring in tables
\usepackage{color} %allows creation of custom colors
\definecolor{lightergray}{RGB}{242,242,242} % define a color for later use
\definecolor{mediumgray}{RGB}{191,191,191} % define a color for later use
\usepackage{booktabs} %enables some nice formatting options in tables
\usepackage{hhline} %% Alternative horizontal line for tables

%% Standard typeset settings
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

%% Package for using external pdf pages
\usepackage{pdfpages}

%% allows better page layouts
\pagestyle{scrheadings} %same as above

%% Use of standard units
\usepackage{siunitx}

%% Define customized pagenumbering, might be obsolete
\newcommand{\custompagenumbers}{%
\break%
\pagenumbering{arabic}%
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{section}\-\arabic{page}}%
}
%% Let each section start on a new page
\let\stdsection\section
\renewcommand\section{%
\setcounter{page}{1}%
\clearpage%
\stdsection%
}

%% Creation of header/footer
\clearscrheadfoot    % footer/header layout happens below here
\chead{\raisebox{5mm}{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{logo.png}}}  
\ofoot{\raisebox{-5mm}{\thesection-\thepage}} 
\cfoot{\raisebox{-5mm}{Title}} 
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}

\usepackage{tikz} %needed for some magic
\usepackage{forloop} %needed to create multiple looped outputs
\usepackage{xparse} %needed to be able to calculate with integer values

\usepackage{sansmath} %load font for math without serifs
\sansmath %set all mathfont to the sansmath font

%% Create variable for later use
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\eval}{m}{\int_eval:n {#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

%% This should be the last entry
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

%Define a default counter for forloops and pgfmarks
\newcounter{forloopcount}
\newcounter{linespgf}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
```

Comment: first of all, check the log file for those pages.  if something has exceeded the capacity, there should be an "overfull vbox" warning.  this could apply to just the header, or to the full page.  what to do differs, depending on which it is.  if you add the relevant warning messages to your question, i think a workable example can be constructed, using a "standard" class like `artlcle', that can then be experimented with.

Comment: I'll give it a try first thing in the morning. A first quick look suggests that there are a lot of overfull hboxes but no overfull vboxes, but I'll have a look in detail tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: There is a bug in fancyhdr which can make the footer move down. But I don't know a case of a header moving up.

Comment: If you are using `fancyhdr` check the output for any warnings telling you that the `\headheight` is too small and modify accordingly. Make sure that you are not setting any page layout dimensions directly so that `geometry` doesn't know about them. What do you mean that the *content* of the header/footer changes?

Comment: Thanks everybody so far. I'll have a look in the mentioned suggestions in a bit. For what it's worth, I added the complete preamble (I didn't delete anything on purpose to give you a complete impression).

Comment: @barbarabeeton I looked into it. I found no vox-warnings whatsoever in the log-files, however as already said, there are plenty of overfull hboxes e.g. `Overfull \hbox (5.14192pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 89-89` However, as far as I understand the log-file, these errors are not linked to the "jumping" header/footer-pages...

Comment: @cfr Please see my posted preamble, the only geometrychanges are regarding the left margin to indent all section headings... The _content_ itself does not change, the format changes. Also - I just noticed - strangely when the footer "jumps", the distance between the text in the footer and the horizontal line above changes as well.

Comment: You are using both `scrlayer-scrpage` and `geometry` to control the page layout. I'd expect that to cause problems, although I can't say if it causes the particular issue you're concerned with here.

Comment: @cfr that's actually a very valid point. However: changing my layout so `scrlayer-scrpage` only sets the content of the header/footer and not indenting the section titles does not change anything in regards to my problems.

Comment: But doesn't `scrlayer-scrpage` have to make changes to the page layout to accommodate the headers/footers etc.? I'm not sure about this as I'm not that familiar with KOMA.

Comment: I tried removing the geometry-package from my whole project: the weird skips still occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just solved the problem.

As always, the error was caused by sloppy programming. At some points in my document - before implementing custom vertical spacings in my tables - I used the `\setstretch{}` command. This command obviously also has an influence on the vertical spacing in the header/footer and therefore created the problem all along. Removing it and using a constant vertical spacing throughout the whole document resolved the issue.

Thanks to everybody who tried to help.